# MongoDB Aggregate search with comma separated string list in array

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB question. I have a search in an aggregation with $match.
Search should check an array if one of the values matches a value of the array inside the documents.

As an example:

```
var stringList = 'general,online,offline'; //--> should check each value of this list
```

and two documents as an example

```
    { 
"_id" : ObjectId("5e8f3a64ec717a0013d2f1f9"), 
"category" : [
    "general", 
    "online", 
    "internal", 
    "miscellaneous"
]},

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5e8f3afeec717a0013d2f1fa"), 
"category" : [
    "offline"
]
```

}

I´ve tried a lot but I don´t found out how it is possible to check each value of the string list with each value in the category array. My example should show both documents, but if I use $in I don´t get any result.

What I tried is:

- Split the list by comma and map
- use of $elemMatch
- use if $in
- use combination of $elemMatch and $in

I hope I could explain my problem with my aggregation.

Thx everyone for his help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to split the string on `,` with `.split` function, then pass this in to a $in query.

```js
var stringList = 'general,online,offline';

db.documents.find( { "category" : { $in : stringList.split(",") } } );
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8f3a64ec717a0013d2f1f9"), "category" : [ "general", "online", "internal", "miscellaneous" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8f3afeec717a0013d2f1fa"), "category" : [ "offline" ] }
```

You can also do this in a $match in an aggregation query.

```js
> db.documents.aggregate([
  { $match : { category: { $in : stringList.split(",") } }}
])
```

Comment: 0
Thanks Kevin... but....

I need this in aggregation... Is it the same way? I thought that I´ve tried this in the same way

Comment: It's totally the same you'll just need to include a `$match` stage. I've included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, where we can search the array name from by using the regex method in the query.

```
var x = ["sai","test","jacob","justin"],
regex = x.join("|");

db.documents.find({
"firstName": {
    "$regex": regex, 
    "$options": "i"
} 
});
```